# What is this w3wp.exe error while browsing the website?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, w3wp.exe

My asp.net website hosted on window server 2008 has suddenly stoped working. When i browse the website an exception is shown on the server saying something about w3wp.exe error. Even if i run the website in visual studio on server it still not working. I have tried a lot to fix it but could not find a solution.

Here is the screen shot of the error on event viewer:
[image]

Can anyone here help me fix it?

Thanks

Comment: scroll down below and paste stacktrace or entire error here or some where else like `pastebin.com`.

Comment: If you have the site, start debugging and attach to that process (and enable break on exception). Should give you some insight on the actual problem (if the stack trace is unhelpful).